# Quickfixj: How can I catch java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information

Tags: exception, connection, try-catch, quickfix

I have FIX initiator running on multiple servers. Idea is to let only one of them have FIX session running on it. However, as soon as FIX session is established on one server, I start getting  java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information on the other server (in its FIX logs).
Is there a way I can catch this exception, or maybe, any means by which I can identify and act on this situation?
Actually, I want the other servers to stop trying to establish FIX connection aimlessly!

Comment: What is the idea to have several initiators trying to connect to an acceptor when you want ot use just one?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is less than clear as to whether the error is on the server that is connected or the other servers. If it is on the other servers this is expected behaviour as they will be unable to connect since there is already a connection on that acceptor. If the error is on the connected server it is possible that the connecting servers are interrupting the connection but that is rather unlikely so the bug may be elsewhere.